# UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell: expand to full size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm looking to an approach to implement the layout as shown below:

[image: layout example]

Essentially, it consists of the `UICollectionViewCell` with an instance of `UITableView` inside it. The `UICollectionViewCell` contains few other supplementary elements, but those are irrelevant for this question.

I'd like the UITableView to be fully expanded, i.e. show all of the cells. I've chosen `UITableView` as it has exactly the style I need.

The problem is that the `UITableView` is not fully expanded. Technically speaking, I'd like the size of the `UITableView` be equal to its `contentSize`.

I'm using AutoLayout to calculate `UICollectionViewCell` size, therefore the "resizable" UITableView would come handy.

So far, I've tried using this approach:

```
import UIKit

final class FullSizeTableView: UITableView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

And then using the `FullSizeTableView` in the `UICollectionViewCell`:
[image]

I've constrained the `UITableView` from all of the 4 sides, at the top to the `UIStackView` and at the bottom, left and right to the `ContentView`.

However, the result looks like this:

[image: incorrect result]

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4 /// Meanwhile, Returning 4 rows in the DataSource
    }
```

So, I guess, the AutoLayout doesn't seem to respect the actual size of the `UITableView`.
What could be potential pitfalls that I'm not accounting for?

My goal for the `UITableView` is to always be fully expanded and shown in full size.

Update1:

Scrolling is already disabled
[image]

Comment: UITableView is-a UIScrollView. The inner content (Cells) won’t ever force the scroll view to expand. You need to enforce the height with an explicit constraint. Though your approach with intrinsicContentSize does seem like a logical path, scrollviews are wierd.

Comment: I think disable tableview scrollable to make this happen.

Comment: @King.lbt it's already disabled, so doesn't work.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Interesting suggestion. What should I constrain to what?

Comment: Do you have any breaking constraints in the console? Following up on @WarrenBurton's comment, if your table view rows are not dynamic height, you could just add a height constraint to the tableView, `numberOfRows * rowHeight`. But at this point, I would question the use of table view. Because a full height table view will allocate all cells at once and not do any dequeuing. You might as well just use a scroll view and add subviews to it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I have breaking constraints, but the message is only displayed once and then it doesn't show up again as I scroll the cells.

Comment: Why should I use the ScrollView? I think of StackView or UIView to be an interesting approach here. Since the table area shouldn't scroll at all, it just looks as the tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this -

```
class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet{
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return contentSize
}

override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is exactly the solution I was looking for. It works nicely with AutoLayout and StackViews and Self-Sizing cells. I've achieved exactly the result I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the height of each row and set your tableView's height to the sum of that.

Here is a simple function that should do that (haven't tested it so it might need some tweaks):

```
func calculateTableViewContentHeight(tableView: UITableView) -> CGFloat {
    let rows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) // adapte to your needs
    var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
    for i in 0..<rows {
        totalHeight += tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)).height
    }
    return totalHeight
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll test it and get back!